# How to add overlay to images in bxSlider

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, overlay, bxslider

I need to add an dark overlay to an image in a bxSlider that will disappear on mouseover, how would I go about doing this?

Other answers I have seen first lighten the image with an opacity of .7, but is there a way to have a dark overlay ontop of an image that disappears on mouseover, similar to the following website: http://www.renegadecraft.com/

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is [image tint](http://www.impressivewebs.com/image-tint-blend-css/)

```
.tint:before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background: rgba(0,255,255, 0.5); /* color you want, in this case, probably black */
    -moz-transition: background .3s linear;
    -webkit-transition: background .3s linear;
    -o-transition: background .3s linear;
    transition: background .3s linear;
}

.tint:hover:before {
    background: none;
}
```